# Rudimentary autograd implementation in Rust

Tags: rust, autograd

I am using Rust to build a simple autograd implementation based on [Karpathy's micrograd](https://github.com/karpathy/micrograd) as inspiration, which was written in Python. I am struggling in building the data structure to manage the children. The following is my initial attempt:

```
enum Op {
    Add,
    Sub,
    Mul,
    Div,
}

struct Value<T: Default> {
    data: T,
    grad: T,
    children: Vec<Rc<RefCell<Value<T>>>>,
    op: Option<Op>
}
```

The problem is that, when building the children type, copying is required. In C, I'd use a raw pointer in this situation. How do I go about doing this in Rust? I've tried using `Vec<&mut Value<T>>` instead, but this leads to hassle if I want to implement the `Add` traits.

Comment: `#[derive(Clone)]` is your friend.

Comment: @user1937198 Yeah, my issue is more so that there is cloning in the first place but after some reading apparently its quite difficult to model graph structures in rust without going unsafe of using Rc<RefCell<T>> types

Comment: For graphs I recommend [`petgraph`](https://docs.rs/petgraph).